# URLs are proxied by react-scripts only when they are called via curl or axios

Tags: reactjs, curl, browser, proxy, axios

I found an interesting case in one of the react-scripts apps where the proxy is configured to `localhost:3001` (the front end is running on `localhost:3000`).

From the react stuff we make a request via `axios` to `localhost:3000/api/results` and that loads a bunch of JSON information, but if I open `localhost:3000/api/results` in a new browser tab that does not display the JSON but loads the HTML instead.

Why is that happening?

The real problem is that we have endpoint to download files from, like:`localhost:3001/api/downloads/csv/file.csv`, but they won't work, because when `localhost:3000/api/downloads/csv/file.csv` is not proxied to `localhost:3001/api/downloads/csv/file.csv` and we simply cannot call this via axios because it should be a direct call from the browser.

However, the strange thing is why does it work via axios and curl?

By doing `curl localhost:3000/api/downloads/csv/file.csv` (or `3001`), we get the right content back.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `react-scripts`, then this is facilitated by **Service Workers**. Quoting from [Service Workers - By Ankita Masand](https://hackernoon.com/service-workers-62a7b14aa63a)...

> *Service Worker acts as a proxy server that intercepts the network requests sent by your web application to the server. In the sense, requests to fetch Javascript or CSS files, images go through service worker to the server. Service Worker has the ability to modify this request or send a custom response back to the client.*

Here, Service Workers are acting as a Client Side Proxy and tapping to your HTTP Requests and you get the right content back.